# Some basic Inheritance problems in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I am learning OO in C++ programming these days in VS2010. I meet with some basic Inheritance problems in C++. Here is my code:

**Question 1:**

```
class bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};

class A:virtual public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};


class B:virtual public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};

class D:virtual public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};


class C:public A,public B,public D
{

};
```

The compiler gives me the error C2250. When I remove the virtual inheritance from each class. i.e.

```
class bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};

class A:public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};


class B:public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};

class D:public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};


class C:public A,public B,public D
{

};
```

it takes effect. Also,if I rewrite the `virtual void name(){};` in class C in the error code,the compiler goes well.So my question is why it is necessary to force to rewrite the virtual function in virtual inheritance situation,and unnecessary to non-virtual inheritance situation.

**Question 2:**

As the code above,when I want to add the `bs *mybs = new C();` in the non-virtual inheritance situation

```
class bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};

class A:public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};


class B:public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};

class D:public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};


class C:public A,public B,public D
{
    virtual void name(){};
};

//bs *mybs = new C(); //C2594
```

the compiler says error C2594. But when in virtual inheritance situation,the compiler has no error.

```
class bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};

class A:virtual public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};


class B:virtual public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};

class D:virtual public bs
{
public:
    int a;
    virtual void name(){};
};


class C:public A,public B,public D
{
    virtual void name(){};
};

bs *mybs = new C();//It is OK
```

What's the matter in virtual inheritance situation?

I think these two questions are not difficult but basic in C++. However,I am not familiar with the OO in C++ version. Thank you for solving the problems.

Comment: Post the compiler error text, so we don't have to look it up?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fts3ys1.aspx , http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/multiple-inheritance.html

Comment: So sorry that my VS2010 is not the version in English.The error texts are all in other language :(

Comment: You should provide implementation of virtual method, because compiler does not know which `name()` to use in `C`: `A::name()`, `B::name()`, `D::name()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: given virtual inheritance, the derived class only gets one instance of the `bs` object, yet there are three implementations of `name()`, and it doesn't know which to use.  If you derive non-virtually, then there are three bs bases embedded in the A, B and D classes, each of which can override the implementation.  Alternatively, you have found that you can replace the ambiguous implementations after virtual inheritance with one implementation in C.

Q2: in the non-virtual situation, you have three `bs` bases in the embedded A, B and D objects: which of these do you want a pointer to?  It's ambiguous so you get the error.  If you used virtual inheritance, then there's only one `bs` base object and you can get a pointer to it.

To illustrate:

```
 VIRTUAL            NON-VIRTUAL
 .       bs          bs  bs  bs
 .     /  |  \       |   |   |
 .     A  B  D       A   B   D
 .     \  |  /        \  |  /
 .        C              C
```

On the left, your problem was `C` didn't know which of `A::name()`, `B::name()` or `D::name()` to use unless you overrode all three in `C`.

On the right, your problem was that `b* my_b_ptr` didn't know which `bs` base to point at.